# what is the max key length and max size of value in memcached?

Tags: spring, macos, memcached

I am using the memcached latest , may i know what is the max key length ,and max size of the value we can store in the memcached ?

How to integrate the memcached with spring , any idea please .

Answer (score 72):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/memcached.h) the max size of the key is 250 bytes. (look for the `KEY_MAX_LENGTH` key)

The Maximum size of the object is 1MB by default. But there is an easy way where you can change that by making minor changes in the config. You can look at [this](http://www.alphadevx.com/a/387-Changing-the-maximum-item-size-allowed-by-Memcache).

On integrating memcached with spring, Am not very sure, But you can look at [this](https://github.com/ragnor/simple-spring-memcached). It has details on how to use it [here](https://github.com/ragnor/simple-spring-memcached/wiki/Getting-Started).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Beautiful answer with link to source. This answer should be accepted.

Comment: @pratikvasa max key size is 250 characters not 250 bytes.